# What are [..] called above enum / class definition?

Tags: c#

Sorry for the silly question, but I came across the following C# code and I'm wondering what the ***[Flags]*** portion is and what it does.

```
[Flags]
public enum UserFlags
{
     //...
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Invalid syntax is what I'd call it.

Comment: Looks like C#, not Java, in which case this is a called an `Attribute`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Are you certain it isn't C# code you came across?

Comment: That is not Java; it looks like C#, where `[...]` is used for [annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/). In Java it would be `@Flags` instead of `[Flags]`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. Yes, it's C# indeed, my bad. I got this while searching for Java solutions so I didn't notice that it was C#.

Comment: @Jesper They're called attributes in C#.

Comment: And just as an extra bit of information, the actual class name for that attribute is `FlagsAttribute`.  The _Attribute_ portion of the class name can be omitted in code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a class attribute. There are also method attributes for example.

You can even write [your own](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx)

They are usually used to define meta information or behaviour about a class or method and can be read using reflection.